# How to ensure that a SSH and HTTPs-url of a repo refer to same git repository

Tags: http, github, ssh

Our platform enables creating applications and connecting them to Git repositories to manage them. We do support GitHub, Azure, Bitbucket etc. Let's suppose we have an application linked to a GitHub repo using HTTPs. We would like to provide the capability to the users to switch to SSH authentication at any point of time, which requires the URL to be changed. This could mean that the user can by mistake enter a URL of a different repository and link to it. How do we prevent this ? Is there a way to find out that the repository pointed by the previous url and the changed url is the same irrespective of the Git Repository Management System used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the user specify a new URL: modify the existing URL.

Consider a fictional Github URL:

```
https://github.com/jdoe/project.git
```

To replace that with an SSH URL, you simply replace `https://github.com/` with `git@github.com:`.

Similar, though different, mappings would need to be coded for each supported Git provider. For example, on Azure it looks like only the user name `U` and the project name `P` is important; they can be extracted from one type of URL and used to construct another type of URL.

- HTTP: http://@dev.azure.com/<USER>/<PROJECT>/_git/<PROJECT>
- SSH: git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/<USER>/<PROJECT>/<PROJECT>

Regardless of the provider, the user need only provide *a* URL *once*; you will handle conversions from one scheme to another behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That works for a repository in github.com. But in case of azure the url looks like below :

https://kt@dev.azure.com/kt/mast_gs_lm/_git/mast_gs_lm and ssh looks like git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/kt/mast_gs_lm/mast_gs_lm and similarly it differs for bitbucket. Given that we are supporting multiple Git repo management systems, how do we make sure that we map to the right repo ?

Comment: There's no universal mapping that will support any Git provider (because there is no standard that says how they must design their URLs), but for a given provider, it should be straightforward to convert URLs with different schemes to one another.

Comment: Yes, so given one http/ssh url, is it possible to get the other url from the remote ? That would save us from conversions for independent providers.

Comment: That would again depend on the provider. Nothing in Git itself says anything about what URLs may or may not exist for any given repository.